# SQL statement confusion, timestamps return inaccurate results

Tags: mysql, date, select, timestamp, max

am getting kind of confused with how my sql statement works. I am trying to select a data called 'vote' from date ranges e.g. 'Top vote of the month', 'Top vote of the week' etc..
Here is where the problem lies. My sql statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM studentid.questions 
WHERE vote IN (
                SELECT MAX(vote) 
                FROM studentid.questions 
                WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2020 
                AND WEEK(timestamp, 4) = 21
            );
```

In my case, the top vote of the week (05/21/2020) should be 2 votes which is correct, but it displays data from january and february that has 2 votes as well. Check the picture link below to see the results..which simply does not match.
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat the date conditions in the outer query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM studentid.questions 
WHERE vote IN (
    SELECT MAX(vote) 
    FROM studentid.questions 
    WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2020 AND WEEK(timestamp, 4) = 21
) AND
    YEAR(timestamp) = 2020 AND
    WEEK(timestamp, 4) = 21;
```

Perhaps you can just use `LIMIT` here instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM studentid.questions 
WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2020 AND WEEK(timestamp, 4) = 21
ORDER BY vote DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1am here, and I have been working for 14 days straight...miracle I even got this answer out in any shape at all `:-)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Both actually work. But its weird that repeating the same thing in the outer query would work...why is it so? Shouldn't the inner query have handled the extraction based on timestamp ranges?? If you are not too tired from working too much, could you explain it to me? If you are, then it is fine if you don't answer

Comment: @WickedLook Here is the idea: Your subquery in fact finds the correct vote count, _for that particular year and week_.  In the outer query, you are only checking the vote count, and it so happens, for your data, that some other year-week _also_ had that max vote count.  So, you need to restrict the date in the outer query as well.

Comment: Thank you sir! That was a very sound explanation.